# Actions On Google Async Issue: Error: No response has been set

Tags: node.js, promise, actions-on-google, google-home

Receiving the following error on my Google Diaglogflow intent from the intent below. The `console.log("res", res)` is correctly logging the JSON, but `Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?` is logged immediately before it.

```
app.intent(DO_MY_THING, conv => {
  console.log("DO_MY_THING");
  axios
    .get("example.com")
    .then(res => {
      console.log("res", res);
      conv.close("Did the thing");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("err", err);
      conv.close("didnt do the thing");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing an asynchronous callback, you need to `return` the Promise object.

```
app.intent(DO_MY_THING, conv => {
  console.log("DO_MY_THING");
  return axios
    .get("example.com")
    .then(res => {
      console.log("res", res);
      conv.close("Did the thing");
    })
   .catch(err => {
     console.log("err", err);
     conv.close("didnt do the thing");
   });
});
```